# Quenya for “hold” as in “to hold a belief”

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, languages, elves, tolkien-languages

Does anyone know if there is any word in Quenya that is well suited for translating “hold” as in “to hold a belief?”

The context if “Fire and Ice” by Robert Frost:

> Some say the world will end in fire
>
> Some say in ice
>
> From what I know of desire
>
> I hold with those who favor fire
>
> But if it had to perish twice
>
> I think I know enough of hate
>
> To say that for destruction ice
>
> Is also great
>
> And would suffice

Comment: Ah, that does change things (not that I know Quenya). You mean "to hold a belief" - originally I was thinking tactically, as in "to hold ground". :)

Comment: @JohnC In English, at least, the two are related, since the notion of "holding" a belief comes, as I understand things, from the notion of "holding" that ground, as in a debate.

Comment: I suggest "stand"- #tar-

Comment: This quotation helps significantly in determining a potential reference. Thank you.

Comment: @AdeleC I'd love to see that as a fleshed out answer to compare with Almare's suggestion of *hep-*

Comment: Working on it....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Parma Penyane Quettaron](http://www.elvish.org/gwaith/ppq/ppq.htm) gives *hep-* for "retain, keep, do not give away or release, keep hold of", unattested in Quenya but derived from the stem KHEP. That's the best I could find, hope it is helpful.

To expand on tar- "stand" as suggested above: this is attested in Parma Eldalamberon 17:71 in the past tense (tarnë). I don't have PE so I can't check attested context, so unsure if it would work in this sense.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this: what does it mean to say that it's unattested by derived from this stem?

Comment: That there is no example of Tolkien using the word, but the stem is given by Tolkien with that meaning and the Quenya word was constructed from that. The root (in Primitive Quendian) is KHEP- which would have become hep- in Quenya which is known from comparison to other words where we have both the root and the Quenya attested.